# how to correctly write vector to binary file in c++?

Tags: c++, fstream

first sorry for my bad english. i am just joined this forum and search for
how to correctly write vector to binary file. i just got from this forum an answer like this(i have modified it a little):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
char m_name[30];
int m_score;

public:
Student()
{

}
Student(const char name[], const int &score)
:m_score(score)
{
    strcpy(m_name, name);
}
void print() const
{
    cout.setf(ios::left);
    cout.width(20);
    cout << m_name << " " << m_score << endl;
}
};


int main()
{
    vector<Student> student;
    student.push_back(Student("Alex",19));
    student.push_back(Student("Maria",20));
    student.push_back(Student("muhamed",20));
    student.push_back(Student("Jeniffer",20));
    student.push_back(Student("Alex",20));
    student.push_back(Student("Maria",21));

    ofstream fout("data.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    fout.write((char*) &student, sizeof(student));
    fout.close();

    vector<Student> student2;

    ifstream fin("data.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    fin.seekg(0, ifstream::end);
    int size = fin.tellg() / sizeof (student2);
    student2.resize(size);
    fin.seekg(0, ifstream::beg);
    fin.read((char*)&student2, sizeof(student2));
    vector<Student>::const_iterator itr = student2.begin();
    while(itr != student2.end())
    {
            itr->print();
            ++itr;
    }
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

but when i run it. on my linux mint i got this result:

> ```
> Alex                 19
> Maria                20
> muhamed              20
> Jeniffer             20
> Alex                 20
> Maria                21
> *** glibc detected *** ./from vector to binary: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000000633030 ***
> ```

i am new to c++.
some one please help me, been stuck in this problem last 2 weeks.
thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Standard hints: compile with `g++ -Wall -g`, improve your code till no warnings are given, learn to use `gdb` and `valgrind` to debug it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are writing to file the vector structure, not its data buffer. Try change writing procedure to:

```
ofstream fout("data.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
fout.write((char*)&student[0], student.size() * sizeof(Student));
fout.close();
```

And instead of calculation size of vector from file size, it's better write vector size (number of objects) before. In the case you can write to the same file other data.

```
size_t size = student.size();
fout.write((char*)&size, sizeof(size));
```

Comment: just a note, `ios::out` isn't needed while using `ofstream` which is already an inherited class for file stream output

Answer (score 27):

To store a `vector<T>` **of [PODs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)** in a file, you have to write the contents of the vector, not the vector itself. You can access the raw data with `&vector[0]`, address of the first element (given it contains at least one element). To get the raw data length, multiply the number of elements in the vector with the size of one element:

```
strm.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&vec[0]), vec.size()*sizeof(T));
```

The same applies when you read the vector from the file; The element count is the total file size divided by the size of one element
(given that you only store one type of POD in the file):

```
const size_t count = filesize / sizeof(T);
std::vector<T> vec(count);
strm.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vec[0]), count*sizeof(T));
```

This only works if you can calculate the number of elements based on the file size (if you only store one type of POD or if all vectors contain the same number of elements). If you have vectors with different PODs with different lengths, you have to write the number of elements in the vector to the file before writing the raw data.

Furthermore, when you transfer numeric types in binary form between different systems, be aware of [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 4):

You probably cannot write in binary (the way you are doing) any `std::vector` because that template contains internal pointers, and writing and re-reading them is meaningless.

Some general advices:

- don't write in binary any STL template containers (like `std::vector` or `std::map`), they surely contain internal pointers that you really don't want to write as is. If you really need to write them, implement your own writing and reading routines (e.g. using STL iterators).
- avoid using `strcpy` without care. Your code will crash if the name has more than 30 characters. At least, use `strncpy(m_name, name, sizeof(m_name));` (but even that would work badly for a 30 characters name). Actually, `m_name` should be a `std::string`.
- serialize explicitly your container classes (by handling each meaningful member data). You could consider using [JSON](http://www.json.org/) notation (or perhaps [YAML](http://yaml.org/), or maybe even XML -which I find too complex so don't recommend) to serialize. It gives you a textual dump format, which you could easily inspect with a standard editor (e.g. `emacs` or `gedit`). You'll find a lot of serializing free libraries, e.g. [jsoncpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/) and many others.
- learn to compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and to use the `gdb` debugger and the `valgrind` memory leakage detector; also learn to use `make` and to write your `Makefile`-s.
- take advantage that Linux is free software, so you can look into its source code (and you may want to study stdc++ implementation even if the STL headers are complex).

Answer (score 4):

For functions read() and write(), you need what is called "plain old data" or "POD". That means basically that the class or structure must have no pointers inside them, and no virtual functions. the implementation of vector certainly has pointers - I'm not sure about virtual functions.

You will have to write a function that stores a student at a time (or that translates a bunch of students to a array [not a vector] of bytes or some such - but that's more complex).

The reason you can't write non-POD data, in particular pointers, to a binary file is that when you read the data back again, you can almost certainly bet that the memory layout has changed from when you wrote it. It becomes a little bit like trying to park in the same parking space at the shops - someone else will have parked in the third spot from the entrance when you turn up next time, so you'll have to pick another spot. Think of the memory allocated by the compiler as parking spaces, and the student information as cars.

[Technically, in this case, it's even worse - your vector doesn't actually contain the students inside the class, which is what you are writing to the file, so you haven't even saved the information about the students, just the information about where they are located (the number of the parking spaces)]