# Write a vector of cv::Mat to binary file in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, binary, ifstream, ofstream

As in the title, I have `std::vector<cv::Mat> matrices` which I want to write/read to/from binary file.

Now, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089675/4480180) answer, all I should do is for writing is:

```
 ofstream fout("matrices.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
 size_t size = matrices.size();
 fout.write((char*)&size, sizeof(size));
 fout.write((char*)&matrices[0], v.size() * sizeof(cv::Mat));
 fout.close();
```

However, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/4480180) answer, writing `cv::Mat` objects seems a little bit tricky, and in the answer `matRead` and `matWrite` do the job. So I wonder if instead of the code above I should do something like:

```
ofstream fout("matrices.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
size_t size = matrices.size();
fout.write((char*)&size, sizeof(size));
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < matrices.size() ; i++)
  matWrite("matrices.bin", matrices[i]);
```

However this code doesn't work since `matWrite()` overwrites `matrices.bin` at each cycle, so I should append the size of `matrices[i]` as offset before writing the matrix itself.

What should I do?

**UPDATE:**

I came up with this solution, rewriting `matWrite` and `matRead` with optional arguments for appending matrices during writing and starting to read from a certain point:

```
void matwrite(const std::string& filename, const cv::Mat& mat, const bool append = false) {

    std::ofstream fs;
    if(append)
        fs.open(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::app);
    else
        fs.open(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::binary);

//the rest of matwrite is the same...

}

cv::Mat matRead(const std::string& filename, size_t &offset = 0)
{
    std::ifstream fs(filename, std::fstream::binary);
    fs.seekg(offset);
    ...
    offset += 4 * sizeof(int) + CV_ELEM_SIZE(type) * rows * cols; //update offset //move offset of 4 ints and mat size
    return mat;
}
```

And functions are called with:

```
//writing:
for(size_t i = 0 ; i<v.size() ; i++)
  writemat(filename, v[i], true);
//reading:
size_t offset = 0;
for(size_t i = 0 ; i<size ; i++){ // size = v.size() during writing
  cv::Mat mat = matRead(filename, offset);
  v.push_back(mat);
}
```

Comment: I'm really curious to know why someone gave me a downvote for this questio

Comment: A note on the duplicate. You can iterate trough each matrix in your vector, and use "matappend".

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't help, let me know. However, now you should be able to write a correct function yourself

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't help. With `matAppend` we write one big matrix, which is the concatenation of all the matrices in the vector. However, it's impossible to reconstruct the original vector starting from the obtained `.bin` file. In few words, we can write `std::vector<cv::Mat>` to file as a big `cv::Mat` but we cannot obtain the `std::vector<cv::Mat>` again.

Comment: @Miki Look at my **UPDATE** section and please let me know what you think

Comment: Tomorrow...... ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt the code of [`matread` and `matwrite`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845) to be used with vectors if `Mat`, instead of single `Mat`. The functions `vecmatread` and `vecmatwrite` below allow to write a `std::vector<cv::Mat>` to a file, and read the vector back:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void vecmatwrite(const string& filename, const vector<Mat>& matrices)
{
    ofstream fs(filename, fstream::binary);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < matrices.size(); ++i)
    {
        const Mat& mat = matrices[i];

        // Header
        int type = mat.type();
        int channels = mat.channels();
        fs.write((char*)&mat.rows, sizeof(int));    // rows
        fs.write((char*)&mat.cols, sizeof(int));    // cols
        fs.write((char*)&type, sizeof(int));        // type
        fs.write((char*)&channels, sizeof(int));    // channels

        // Data
        if (mat.isContinuous())
        {
            fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(0), (mat.dataend - mat.datastart));
        }
        else
        {
            int rowsz = CV_ELEM_SIZE(type) * mat.cols;
            for (int r = 0; r < mat.rows; ++r)
            {
                fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(r), rowsz);
            }
        }
    }
}

vector<Mat> vecmatread(const string& filename)
{
    vector<Mat> matrices;
    ifstream fs(filename, fstream::binary);

    // Get length of file
    fs.seekg(0, fs.end);
    int length = fs.tellg();
    fs.seekg(0, fs.beg);

    while (fs.tellg() < length)
    {
        // Header
        int rows, cols, type, channels;
        fs.read((char*)&rows, sizeof(int));         // rows
        fs.read((char*)&cols, sizeof(int));         // cols
        fs.read((char*)&type, sizeof(int));         // type
        fs.read((char*)&channels, sizeof(int));     // channels

        // Data
        Mat mat(rows, cols, type);
        fs.read((char*)mat.data, CV_ELEM_SIZE(type) * rows * cols);

        matrices.push_back(mat);
    }
    return matrices;
}


int main()
{
    vector<Mat> matrices;

    // Fill vector...
    Mat1f m1(3,3);
    randu(m1, 0, 1);

    Mat3b m2(4, 5);
    randu(m2, Scalar(0,0,0), Scalar(256,256,256));

    Mat2d m3(2, 3);
    randu(m3, Scalar(0, 0), Scalar(1, 1));

    matrices.push_back(m1);
    matrices.push_back(m2);
    matrices.push_back(m3);

    // Write the vector to file
    vecmatwrite("test.bin", matrices);

    // Read the vector from file
    vector<Mat> matrices2 = vecmatread("test.bin");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
string   name_1c;
ofstream outFile_1st;
name_1c = "m_scripts/labeled_1.bin";
outFile_1st.open(name_1c, std::ios::binary);

Mat data = Mat::zeros(100, 1024, CV_32FC);
vector<Mat> labeled_1(6);
// initialization of vector
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i ++)
    labeled_1.push_back(randn(data, Scalar(128), Scalar(10)));


for (int i = 0; i < labeled_1.size(); i ++)
{
 outFile_1st.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&labeled_1[i]), sizeof(float) * 100 * 1024);
}
outFile_1st.close();
```