# How to save a vector to a file without "printing" it?

Tags: c++

What do you think would be the best way (especially in terms of space on the hdd/ssd/...) to save (not print) a huge vector (e.g. a vector of 10<sup>9</sup> ints (4gb)) to a file, being able to open/read from/reallocate it in RAM at a later time?

I don't want to print it to the file, because than the file would have the size of one byte per each digit of each number (plus one byte for a ',' or a '\n' or something to separate each number, and another byte for '-' whenever the number is negative...). That, in most cases, would be a waste of space, and would also be a slow approach to re-open it at a later time.

I mean, is it possible to write a vector (or also an array) to a file directly, without representing it in a set of "readable" characters through, for example, NotePad? I'm not interested if any other program won't be capable of read that file.

Comment: Save it as a blob? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe not really. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089689/65863) of the duplicate, in particular, is most relevant to this question.